# Versioning website plugins (e.g. Wibiya bar, Meebo bar)

Tags: javascript, versioning

I'm working on a plugin that will be added to external sites, something like the Meebo/Wibiya bar. I'm looking into how to version my files.

What I want to achieve:

- The website only has to add a few lines of `<script>` to their site.
- I'll be able to silently upgrade the js file they're using, if I choose to, without them modifying their code.
- I'll be able to serve different js files for different websites.
- JS files will be cached unless they change.
- I'll be able to perform A/B tests (i.e., have 2 different JS files loaded for a single website, randomly chosen for each visitor).

How can I go about achieving all these goals? Or at least as many of them as possible?

Comment: Your second and fourth bullet points conflict with each other. Most third party JS plugins deal with this by using a fairly short expire time on their cache. It can still be cached, but you don't want to do long-expiring cache. 24 hours is a common value for third-party scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head, I think something like the following should get things moving.

You could use some sort of API key to identify the remote sites, 
you could also use the HTTP referer but that's not completely
reliable. Then, copy what Google Analytics does and get the clients 
to embed a little bit of JavaScript like this:

```
var _edan_cfg    = _edan_cfg || { };
_edan_cfg.apiKey = 'The-API-key-goes-here'; // Just in case you want it later.
(function() {
    var e   = document.createElement('script');
    e.type  = 'text/javascript';
    e.async = true;
    e.src   = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') 
            + '.your-domain-name.com/some_sensible_path/'
            + encodeURIComponent(_edan_cfg.apiKey);

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(e, s);
})();
```

That should satisfy your first two points.

On the server side you extract the API key from the incoming path, 
that key tells you what site you're talking to so you can send back
whatever JavaScript is appropriate. You can use the HTTP caching 
headers to attempt to control caching. That should take care of
points two and three.

The last requirement is a bit more interesting but nothing impossible. 
The script you send back can always support multiple renderings or
behaviors, the script can also choose which behavior based on
whatever conditions you can think of. The script can also load more 
scripts from your server by creating more `<script>` tags as above.